# IOS need to sort an array of dictionaries value based on key price

Tags: iphone, ios

'm facing problem to sort the values based on key using dictionary object. Actually what i am storing is, each dictionary object having different data type in that dictionary all the data type taking as a string how to convert this string type to specific data type and sort it price vise, my code and out put is bellow, Please help me on this one.

```
-(IBAction)PriceSort:(id)sender
{
    NSSortDescriptor * sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Price" ascending:true] ;
    NSArray *sa = [symbolArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    NSLog(@"price=%@",sa);

}
```

**out put**
 {

```
    volume = 2496752;

    Yield = "10.49";

    MarCap = 829;

    Price = "0.715";

    Symbol = SAIPI;

},
```

Comment: How differnt data types in dictionary, can you show them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"price"
                                                 ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)] ;
```

Please replace this one and try , hope its works .

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)sort
{
    //This is the array of dictionaries, where each dictionary holds a record
    NSMutableArray * array; 
    //allocate the memory to the mutable array and add the records to the arrat

    // I have used simple bubble sort you can use any other algorithm that suites you
    //bubble sort
    //
    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < [array count]; j++)
        {
            NSDictionary *recordOne = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            NSDictionary *recordTwo = [array objectAtIndex:j];

            if([[recordOne valueForKey:@"price"] floatValue] > [[recordTwo valueForKey:@"remaining"] floatValue])
            {
                [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
            }
        }   
    }

    //Here you get the sorted array
}
```

Hope this helps.